# Adjacency matrix of amino-acid residue

Tags: biostatistics, graph-theory, bioinformatics, chemometrics

How to get the mathematical representation of the chemical bonds in protein residue or the whole protein? Is it possible to get the connectivity matrix or a pairwise description?

The example in the photo: PyRosetta Manual, page 16. The full atom representation is stored in */fa_standart/residue_types*. Can it be called just as an inline function?

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Are you trying to get some sort of network out of the output?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=DCEL&rlz=1C1WZPD_enUS385&oq=DCEL&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.701j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Yes, exactly. The network of connectivity of the residue or the protein.